# How can I show a multipart HTML email message in a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, multipart, jeditorpane

Following is the snippet that I am using to fetch and display emails.

```
String email = "";
jEditorPane1.setContentType("text/html");

for( int i=0 ; i<msgs.length ; i++ ) {
    senSub +=  InternetAddress.toString(msgs[i].getFrom()) + "\n" + msgs[i].getSubject() + "\n" + "\n";
    Object o = msgs[i].getContent();
    if( o instanceof String) {
        email += o.toString();
        System.out.println("FIRST IF");
    }  else if( o instanceof Multipart ) {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)o;
        int bodyParts = mp.getCount();
        System.out.println("BODY PARTS---->" + bodyParts ); // There are 2 body parts
            for(int j = 0 ; j < bodyParts ; j++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(j);
                Object o2 = bodyPart.getContent();
                  if( o2 instanceof String ) {
                      email += "--THIS IS THE " + j +  " BODY PART" + "-- " + o2.toString() + "--THIS IS THE END OF FIRST PART--"; 
                  } else if( o2 instanceof Multipart ) {
                      Multipart mp2 = (Multipart)o2;
                      System.out.println("NESTED MULTIPART");
                      int count2 = mp2.getCount();
                        for(int k = 0 ; k < count2 ; k++) {
                            BodyPart bodyPart1 = mp2.getBodyPart(k);
                        }
                  }
            }
    }
}

Font font = new Font("Trebuchet MS" , Font.BOLD , 15);
jTextArea6.setFont(font);
status = false;
jTextArea6.setText(senSub);
jEditorPane1.setText(email); // set the email on the editor pane
```

But it is showing some strange behavior.

**Here is the output : ( in 2 parts )**

[image] 
**part 2**

[image]

**And here is the original email**: 
[image]

Let me explain the output. In the `first body part`*(of multipart message)* the `plain message` + `links of images` are pasted.The in the second part the images in the original email are pasted. With the line *The days of needing.....anywhere* repeated twice. And the second part never gets over. Why is this?

**There are 7 messages in my inbox but only 1 email is displayed, no doubt the code that fetches the email is somewhere wrong.** 
But I can't figure out where it is wrong.
 _Let me tell you that I get the right results corresponding to the statement

`senSub +=  InternetAddress.toString(msgs[i].getFrom()) + "\n" + msgs[i].getSubject() + "\n";` *result is 7 subjects and 7 senders*

**Please tell what is wrong with the code.I want links to pasted as link, text to pasted as text, images to pasted as images and not randomly.**